# Restrict Internet access to a particular app only for a specific time period on an unrooted device

Tags: applications, networking, permissions

I have an app that behaves poorly. It is constantly uploading stuff in the background. I think I could get it to use less power if I could impose some sort of "parental control" type feature on it. I'd like the OS to tell this app (and only this app) that there is no network (wifi/data) connection whenever it asks, except for two separate hours of the day (then if I have a connection, the app can use it for that hour).

Is there any setting that does this?

Comment: Yeah sure! It can be easily done. My first choice would be to use [AFwall+'s](https://github.com/ukanth/afwall) Profile and [Tasker](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.dinglisch.android.taskerm) in combination. But because the former requires root access which you might not be having, so the hint may not be helping much. 2) Because it's about power saving, using firewall might not be a good idea because the poorly coded app would still continuously show up in Firewall logs requesting connection, and all...continued..

Comment: 3) (Still requires root) You can use XPrivacy and Tasker to restrict internet access using permission control for time being but I never really tested whether an app would still continuously demand for that permission and get denied or not. 4) If the app isn't of much use for whole day, then you can use Greenify to hibernate, so it won't be doing anything unless explicitly invoked by user or depending component, 5) You can use Titanium Backup (needs root) to freeze/kill the app for time being if condition in '4)' is satisfied.

Comment: Hmm, I'll check out Greenify. Haven't rooted yet. Might have to try that soon... Thanks for the comments :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This doesn't apply to Wi-Fi, but the Android system has a per-app setting "restrict background data" that will completely stop the app from using mobile data *except* when the app is running in the foreground (i.e. it's the active app).

To access this setting, go to System Settings > Data Usage, then scroll down to locate the app and tap it. Then scroll down to find a checkbox for the setting.

Comment: Marking this as the answer. I looked into greenify, but it wasn't clear what that did for me. This (and disabling bluetooth) will at least prevent the app from draining data, and hopefully power. Thanks!

Comment: Update: it works! My battery's been back to an acceptable level since I "restricted background data". I don't use that app much anyway, so it's great that it's not eating so much power these days.

Comment: Glad to hear it! Also, welcome to Stack Exchange! Be sure to take the [tour](http://android.stackexchange.com/tour), and come back to vote this post up one you've earned enough [reputation](http://android.stackexchange.com/help/privileges). (You're almost there!)